# Pytorch: nn.Sequential gives NaN and Cholesky decomposition gives another error

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, torch

In my quest to build a cGAN transforming a code in tensorflow to pytorch, I stucked with the following:

```
def __init__(self, hilbert_size, num_points, noise=None):
    super(Generator, self).__init__()
    
    self.initializer = nn.init.normal_

    ops = nn.Parameter(torch.empty(1, hilbert_size, hilbert_size, num_points * 2))
    #inputs = torch.empty((1, 1296), requires_grad=True)
    #inputs = torch.empty((1, num_points), requires_grad=True)
    inputs = nn.Parameter(torch.empty((1, num_points)))
    
    layer = nn.Linear(num_points, 16 * 16 * 2, bias=False)
    #init.kaiming_uniform_(layer.weight, a=math.sqrt(5))
    init.normal_(layer.weight, mean=0.0, std=0.02)

    self.x = nn.Sequential(
        layer,
        nn.LeakyReLU(),
        nn.Unflatten(1, (2,16,16))
        #view((-1, 16, 16, 2))
        )
    '''    
    self.x = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(num_points, 16 * 16 * 2, bias=False),
        nn.LeakyReLU(),
        #nn.Reshape((16, 16, 2)),
        nn.Unflatten(1, (2,16,16))
        #nn.Unflatten(1, (16,16,2))
    )
    '''

    self.conv_transpose_1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(2, 64, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False),
        nn.InstanceNorm2d(64),
        #nn.InstanceNorm2d(x.shape[1])
        nn.LeakyReLU(),
    )

    self.conv_transpose_2 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 64, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=2, bias=False),
        nn.InstanceNorm2d(64),
        #nn.InstanceNorm2d(x.shape[1])
        nn.LeakyReLU(),
    )

    self.conv_transpose_3 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=1, bias=False),
    )

    self.conv_transpose_4 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 2, kernel_size=4, stride=1, padding=2, bias=False),
    )

    self.density_matrix = DensityMatrix()
    self.expectation = Expectation()
    self.noise = nn.GaussianNoise(noise)

def forward(self, ops, inputs):
    x = self.x(inputs)
    x = self.conv_transpose_1(x)
    x = self.conv_transpose_2(x)
    x = self.conv_transpose_3(x)
    x = self.conv_transpose_4(x)
    x = self.density_matrix(x)
    complex_ops = convert_to_complex_ops(ops)
    prefactor = 1.0
    x = self.expectation(complex_ops, x, prefactor)
    x = self.noise(x)

    return x
```

where:

```
class DensityMatrix(nn.Module):
    """
    Density matrix layer that cleans the input matrix into a Cholesky matrix
    and then constructs the density matrix for the state
    """

def __init__(self):
    super(DensityMatrix, self).__init__()

def forward(self, inputs):
    """
    The forward function which applies the Cholesky decomposition

    Args:
        inputs (`torch.Tensor`): a 4D real valued tensor (batch_size, hilbert_size, hilbert_size, 2)
                                 representing batch_size random outputs from a neural network.
                                 The last dimension is for separating the real and imaginary part

    Returns:
        dm (`torch.Tensor`): A 3D complex valued tensor (batch_size, hilbert_size, hilbert_size)
                              representing valid density matrices from a Cholesky decomposition of the
                              cleaned input
    """
    T = clean_cholesky(inputs)
    return density_matrix_from_T(T)
```

and

```
def clean_cholesky(img):
    real = img[:, 0, :, :]
    imag = img[:, 1, :, :]

    #diag_all = torch.linalg.diag_part(imag, k=0, padding_value=0)
    #diag_all = torch.diag(imag, k=0, padding_value=0)
    diag_all = torch.diag(imag)
    diags = torch.linalg.diag(diag_all)

    imag = imag - diags
    imag = torch.linalg.band_part(imag, -1, 0)
    real = torch.linalg.band_part(real, -1, 0)
    T = torch.complex(real, imag)
    return T
```

The inputs are:

```
In [154]: inputs
Out[154]: 
tensor([[1.9286e-39, 2.1122e-39, 2.2959e-39,  ..., 4.5779e-41,     2.7162e+20,
     4.5779e-41]], requires_grad=True)
```

And:

```
x = nn.Sequential(
            layer,
            nn.LeakyReLU(),
            nn.Unflatten(1, (2,16,16))
            #view((-1, 16, 16, 2))
            )
```

Gives:

```
In [160]: x
Out[160]: 
Sequential(
  (0): Linear(in_features=1296, out_features=512, bias=False)
  (1): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.01)
  (2): Unflatten(dim=1, unflattened_size=(2, 16, 16))
)
```

But `x = self.conv_transpose_1(x)` gives:

```
Out[250]: 
tensor([[[[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      ...,
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

     [[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      ...,
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

     [[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      ...,
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

     ...,

     [[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      ...,
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

     [[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      ...,
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]],

     [[0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      ...,
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.]]]], grad_fn=<LeakyReluBackward0>)
```

A bunch of zeros, and I have no idea why!!!
And when I use `torch.linalg.cholesky` it gives the error:

```
_LinAlgError: linalg.cholesky: (Batch element 0): The factorization could not be completed because
the input is not positive-definite (the leading minor of order 1 is not positive-definite).
```

And if I use my defined `clean_cholesky` function it gives another error:

```
ll_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
Cell In[421], line 24, in DensityMatrix.forward(self, inputs)
     10 def forward(self, inputs):
---> 24     T = clean_cholesky(inputs)
     25     return density_matrix_from_T(T)

Cell In[426], line 7, in clean_cholesky(img)
      3 imag = img[:, :, :, 1]
      ----> 7 diag_all = torch.diag(imag)
      8 diags = torch.linalg.diag(diag_all)
     10 imag = imag - diags

RuntimeError: matrix or a vector expected
```

imag is os the form:

```
In [541]: imag
Out[541]: 
tensor([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]],
       grad_fn=<SliceBackward0>)
```

In tensorflow everything works fine and imag is:

```
In [58]: imag
Out[58]: <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 16, 16) dtype=float64 (created by layer 'tf.__operators__.getitem_3')>
```

But something is missing when I try to translate the code from tensorflow to pytorch but I really do not know what or where the error is.

This is is really important for me and any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try first to:

- Fix the indentation in `clean_cholesky`
- Add `__init__` and `forward` methods to `DensityMatrix`

[Edit] I mean that the class needs a `forward`:

```
class DensityMatrix(nn.Module):

    def forward(self, inputs):
        T = clean_cholesky(inputs)
        return density_matrix_from_T(T)
```

Comment: thanks. I already editted the question. The identation was wrong only here when I wrote the question, but it is not a problem in the code itself.
As for the second point, I didn't get it: you mean inside DensityMatrix() class? Is it some peculiarity of torch construction of the layers?